# Polynomial over $\Bbb C$, need to factorise it using remainder theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know how to factorise cubic polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ using the remainder theorem, but I don't know how to do that with this question:

$$x^3 + (-1+3i)x^2 - (2+3i)x + 2 $$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Let $p=x^3 + (-1+3i)x^2 - (2+3i)x + 2$

Before resorting to general methods for cubics, you can check if there is a real root. Then, taking the real part, the equation is $x^3-x^2-2x+2$. The usual [rational root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) has you check $\pm2,\pm1$, of which $1$ is a root. You can see that it's also a root of your original equation, since $3ix^2-3ix$ vanishes for $x=1$.

*[edit, rethinking it: it would have been simpler to look for roots of the imaginary part $3ix^2-3ix=3ix(x-1)$ and check whether they are roots of the real part]*

Then $p=(x-1)(x^2+ax-2)=x^3+(a-1)x^2-(a+2)x-2=x^3 + (-1+3i)x^2 - (2+3i)x + 2$

Hence $a-1=-1+3i$ and $a=3i$.

And $p=(x-1)(x^2+3ix-2)$

We can factor the trinomial: $\Delta^2=-9+8=-1$, thus $x=\dfrac{-3i\pm i}2$, and the roots are $-2i$ and $-i$.

The complete factorization of $p$ is thus:

$$p=(x-1)(x+2i)(x+i)$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the rational root test over $\mathbb{Q}[\text{i}]$ (which works in the same way as the rational root test over $\mathbb{Q}$).  *Integers* in $\mathbb{Q}[\text{i}]$ are in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (also known as the ring of *Gaussian integers*) and therefore, if $p(x):=x^3+(-1+3\text{i})x^2-(2+3\text{i})x+2\in\big(\mathbb{Q}[\text{i}]\big)[x]$ has a *Gaussian-rational* root, then it is a Gaussian integer and divides $2$.  Thus, a Gaussian-rational root of $p(x)$ must be of the form $\pm 1$, $\pm\text{i}$, $\pm1 \pm \text{i}$, $\pm 2$, or $\pm2\text{i}$.  Then, you can easily check that $1$, $-\text{i}$, and $-2\text{i}$ are roots.  Thus, $p(x)=(x-1)(x+\text{i})(x+2\text{i})$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x=1$ is a root, so divide by $x-1$ to obtain the other factor:

$$p(x) = x^3 + (-1+3i)x^2 - (2+3i)x + 2=(x^2+3ix-2)(x-1).$$

This can be done by long division, or by "looking ahead" and working from higher to lower powers of $x$, collecting factors of $x-1$:

$$\begin{align}
p(x)
&= x^3 + (-1+3i)x^2 - (2+3i)x + 2 \\
&= (x-1)[x^2] + 3ix^2 - (2+3i)x + 2 \\
&= (x-1)\left[x^2+3ix\right] - 2x + 2 \\
&= (x-1)\left[x^2+3ix-2\right]
\end{align}$$
At this point, the quadratic formula shows how to factor the remaining quadratic: $$x=\frac{-3i\pm\sqrt{(3i)^2-4(-2)}}{2}=\frac{-3i\pm i}{2}\in\{-i,-2i\}$$ so that $$p(x)=(x-1)(x+i)(x+2i).$$
In general, it is very useful to know the [rational root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), also over [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integers), as @Batominovski points out.